# React typescript, Property 'propTypes' does not exist on type 'typeof TodoFilterItem'. TS2339

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I have an interface

```
interface ITodoFilterItem  {
  name: string,
  filter: string,
  filterTodos: any
}
```

and a class in the same file that references it

```
class TodoFilterItem extends Component<ITodoFilterItem> {
  constructor (props:ITodoFilterItem) {
    super(props);
    this.handleFilter = this.handleFilter.bind(this);
  }
```

but when I try and add propTypes at the bottom of this file with

```
TodoFilterItem.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  filter: PropTypes.string,
  filterTodos: PropTypes.any
}
```

I get:

---

```
Property 'propTypes' does not exist on type 'typeof TodoFilterItem'.  TS2339
```

---

fyi: I have `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` at the top

Comment: Do you need `propTypes` since you're already defining the props via `Component<MyProps, MyState>`? Apart from compile time vs run time, I'd typically just use one or the other.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746028/proptypes-in-a-typescript-react-application

Comment: yes I want to use both in this case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Errors while converting a React project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779183/typescript-errors-while-converting-a-react-project)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TS requires that all static properties are initialized in the class definition. Add the following to your class to ensure TS can analyze the class properly.

```
static propTypes: {
   name: Requireable<string>;
   filter: Requireable<string>;
   filterTodos: Requireable<any>;
};
```

```js
import React, { Component, Requireable } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

interface ITodoFilterItem {
    name: string;
    filter: string;
    filterTodos: any;
}

class TodoFilterItem extends Component<ITodoFilterItem> {
    static propTypes: {
        name: Requireable<string>;
        filter: Requireable<string>;
        filterTodos: Requireable<any>;
    };

    constructor(props: ITodoFilterItem) {
        super(props);
        this.handleFilter = this.handleFilter.bind(this);
    }

    handleFilter() {}

    render() {
        return <span />;
    }
}

TodoFilterItem.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    filter: PropTypes.string,
    filterTodos: PropTypes.any,
};

export default TodoFilterItem;
```